# Can't train a model from scratch using tensorflow-slim

Tags: tensorflow

I just followed slim tutorial for image classification library and made imagenet TFRecord,too.

In [training-a-model-from-scracth](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#training-a-model-from-scratch), followed below code :

```
TRAIN_DIR=/home/ywlee/models/slim/results/
DATASET_DIR=/Data_ssd/ILSVRC2012/TFRecord/
python train_image_classifier.py \
  --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=imagenet \
  --dataset_split_name=train \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=inception_v3
```

However, this error occur.

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key InceptionV3/Conv2d_3b_1x1/weights not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_51 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_51/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_51/shape_and_slices)]]
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_233/_1359 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_576_save/RestoreV2_233", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I understood If I don't indicate the checkpoint, this program inits training without any pre-trained weight.
But I don't know why this error happen.

Second question is,

I can't fully understand the meanings of clone, replica, parameter-server(ps) and worker and confuse between tensorflow multi-gpu manual and slim.

Could you advice how to train using multi-gpu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the TRAIN_DIR=/home/ywlee/models/slim/results/ there is already a checkpoint that the model is trying to load.
Try using a clean directory without any checkpoint inside.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--num_clones=n` can use mutli-gpu, if not, it use one gpu as default.

Clean the TRAIN_DIR is useful to me, maybe it help